# How to get a specific column value when using Datatables Selected_Row

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to get a specific column value when clicking on a datatable row ,currently I can only get the row number of the clicked row. Eg click on the row to get the id column value rather than the rownum in the below table example.

```
rownumber      first_name       second_name        id   
1              Zeze Steven      Sessegnon          192     
2              Zlatan           Ibrahimovic        272  
3              Jack             Wilshere           523
```

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste(length(input$players_rows_selected))  ## This just prints the rownum 
  })
  
 
  output$players <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    master_playeridlist
  }))
}
```

For the life of me I cannot find how to do this ,

I would imagine it would be something like input$players_rows_selected(id)  ?

I had tried adding selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'column') but this doesn't seem to work, and have read over the [options for selection here](https://rdrr.io/cran/DT/src/inst/examples/DT-selection/server.R)

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input$foo_rows_selected` stores the row index of the selected rows.  To get the value of a specific column for the selected row, simply subset the data frame.

```
output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    master_playeridlist[input$players_rows_selected, "id"] 
})
```